# stop process are running from specific directory | Remote server with invoke

Tags: powershell

I want to stop all the processes are running from specific directory
if the process is from C:/CSV/X
kill the process the server is remote but I have users are opened the files from different sessions so how can I kill it from different sessions

```
    $files = gci "C:\CSV\X\*"

foreach($file in $files){
    Get-Process | 
    Where-Object {$_.Path -eq $file.FullName} | 
    Stop-Process -Force -Verbose
}
```

I try this but is not works...

Edit:

For example we have a folder named: MyItem
Inside the folder there is

MyItem/software.exe

MyItem/MyItem.exe

MyItem/MainMenu.exe

And I look for the processes through this: fsmgmt.msc

So I need to find a way to close all those whose source is MyItem/

Comment: Can you give an example of the process you want to stop? Do you want to stop processes where the executable is in that folder, or processes which are locking files in that folder?

Comment: For example we have a folder named: MyItem
Inside the folder there is
MyItem/software.exe
MyItem/MyItem.exe
MyItem/MainMenu.exe

And I look for the processes through this: fsmgmt.msc
So you need to find a way to close all those whose source is MyItem/

Answer (score 0):

If the files are showing up in `fsmgmt.msc`, then you need to close SMB (file sharing) sessions. Try something like this on the file server:

```sh
$folder = 'C:\Share\Folder\*'

# get the list of open files and their SMB sessions
$OpenFiles = Get-SmbOpenFile | Where Path -like $folder
$Sessions  = $OpenFiles | Select SessionID -Unique

# [optionally] print a list of locked files
$OpenFiles | select ClientUserName,Path

# close sessions and open files
$OpenFiles | Close-SmbOpenFile -Force
Close-SmbSession -SessionId $Sessions.SessionID -Force
```

You may see this error, but it just means the file is already closed:

```text
Close-SmbOpenFile : There is not an open file with that identification number.
```

Comment: error:
 Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SessionId'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

Comment: @vfdsabvdasvd it's saying there weren't any open files. Run it again, and check both `$OpenFiles` and `$Sessions` to see if they return anything. If they are empty, then make sure the folder path filter is correct